References on getting the correlation function in a 3D Markov Random Field?
Does anyone know where to look to find analytical formulae for the correlation function of the Ising model on a 2D or 3D lattice (assuming toroidal or infinite is easier?), or, even better, a continuous, Gaussian version of the Ising model that I would call a "Gaussian Markov Random Field."
From Wikipedia it seems that the 2D version (for the Ising model) was solved by Lars Onsanger, and the 3D version (for the Ising model) is still unsolved? But it feels like the Gaussian case might be easier?
Do you know of any references or places I could look? I haven't found anything that hits the spot yet, but it feels like this problem must be solved / someone must have written stuff about it.
The context is: I'm working on a project in spatial statistics where I'm basically using the Ising model, but I'm making it continuous, so it's called a "Gaussian Markov Random Field." Basically, I have a random field Z on a 3D lattice, and I say that $Z$ follows a normal distribution with mean 0 and with precision matrix given by $L(\rho) = D - \rho A$, where $\rho$ is between 0 and 1, and $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the lattice, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with each entry the degree of vertex (so $L$ is basically the graph Laplacian; note that when we are in the toroidal setting, every entry of $D$ is the same, 8 in the 2D case and 26 in the 3D case). This means that the density of $Z$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
p(Z) \propto \exp(-(Z^T L(\rho) Z)/2),
\end{equation*}
or equivalently
\begin{equation*}
Z \sim N(0, L(\rho)^{-1}). 
\end{equation*}
Unless I'm missing something, I think I'm dealing pretty clearly with the analog of the Ising model but in continuous space, where $\rho$ is replacing the conventional notation of $J$ for correlation strength, and I'm not applying any field (and I'm basically considering fixed temperature).
I just want to know how the correlation between two voxels in my 3D lattice changes as a function of $\rho$, because I would like to choose $\rho$ to target a particular length scale.
The closest I've found in Chapter 8 of "Statistical Mechanics of Phases and Phase Transitions" by Kivelson, Jiang, and Chang; this chapter is titled "The Gaussian model."  It provides an integral expression for the correlation function G. But I can't help but wonder...is there really no simpler expression? I feel like someone must have figured this out...
Any leads are appreciated!

At first glance, it looks like the discrete Gaussian Free Field. If yes, then the correlation function coincides (up to some $\rho$-dependent explicit prefactor) with the Green function of a random walk that can be killed at each step with a probability depending on the value of $\rho$. I'd recommend having a look at Chapter 8 of this book. Note that Green functions of killed random walks on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ are well understood objects.
